# Excel VBA - Print out lines based on field value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to figure out how to print a line based on if the cell value = 'y'.

I thought I can use switch statement as there is about 40 rows that I need to check if column 'J' is set to 'y' in the cell. If it does that I need to print the line or skip if it is set to 'n'.  Each 'tmp' below is a new row that I need to test out.

Would I use a if statement to accomplish this?

```
    Sub CellsToFreedom()
          On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
          Dim freedomfile As String: freedomfile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\FromTemplate.txt"
          Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject: Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject: Dim ts As Scripting.TextStream
          Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(freedomfile, ForWriting, True)
          Dim tmp As String, pd As String, jd As String, source As String
          
        tmp = tmp & MakeLine(Cells(6, 1).Value & Cells(6, 2) & Cells(6, 3) & Cells(6, 4).Value & "00", source & "" & pd, Cells(6, 6).Value)
        tmp = tmp & MakeLine(Cells(7, 1).Value & Cells(7, 2) & Cells(7, 3) & Cells(7, 4).Value & "00", source & "" & pd, Cells(7, 6).Value)
        tmp = tmp & MakeLine(Cells(8, 1).Value & Cells(8, 2) & Cells(8, 3) & Cells(8, 4).Value & "00", source & "" & pd, Cells(8, 6).Value)
        tmp = tmp & MakeLine(Cells(9, 1).Value & Cells(9, 2) & Cells(9, 3) & Cells(9, 4).Value & "00", source & "" & pd, Cells(9, 6).Value)
        ts.Write (tmp)
          MsgBox "Freedom file was created."
          writelog "file was created."
        ExitHere:
          ts.Close
          Exit Sub
        ErrorHandler:
          writelog Err.Description & "  " & Err.Number, "CellsToFreedom()", False
          Resume ExitHere
        End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: "Would I use a if statement to accomplish this?" - Yes, or `Select Case`.

Comment: Can you provide me an example on how to accomplish this in the Subroutine?  How would I test all rows to check for 'y' in column J?

Comment: With a loop perhaps.

Comment: Can you provide an example with my code above?

Comment: From the code you posted, it's difficult to see how that fits in a loop over rows, so you likely need to explain a little more...

Comment: I was able to solve it using a for loop with an If statement.